# How to upload multiple files simultaneously using create_deep_entity method?

Tags: odata, sapui5, filestream, sap-gateway

As we all know we can upload files using `create_stream` method in SAP Gateway(oData).

I want to upload multiple files using `Create_Deep_entity` along with `create_stream` method.

How to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard way it is impossible for now. Only one attachment per one call.

However you can try the following trick with **DEEP_INSERT** method:

1. Place your multi-entity table structure into service model
2. Call service with **$expand** property, it will call `CREATE_DEEP_ENTITY` method sequentially
3. Redefine the logic of `CREATE_DEEP_ENTITY` method

Read these articles for more details

[Uploading Files to SAP GW – New Techniques](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/24/uploading-files-to-sap-gw-downloading-files-from-sap-gw-new-techniques/)

[How to Add Multiple Entities in One Operation in OData Service](https://sapyard.com/odata-and-sap-netweaver-gateway-part-ix-how-to-add-multiple-entities-in-one-operation-in-odata-service/)